# Convert postgres bytea string into php byte string

Tags: php, postgresql, binary

I have a string like `\314\002\012\001` which I need to convert into a *base64* encoded byte string.

Comment: Are you using a binary data type in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the built-in php function [pg_unescape_bytea](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-unescape-bytea.php). There is an example on that page.